Can Cognito custom authentication be used to authenticate by password?
The reason why I am doing this,  to do MFA with a security key that normal cognito does not support for 2-step authentication.
I was able to implement this to the point where I can successfully log in with a security key using custom authentication for primary authentication.
However, I need to perform ID/PW authentication in the custom authentication to authenticate with the security key after the password authentication. When custom authentication is specified for primary authentication and PASSWORD_VERIFIER is specified for challengeName, the authentication challenge definition trigger is not ignite when authenticateUser is used on the client.
Is there any way to resolve this issue? Client code is nextjs or pure React.
there are lambda for define challenge auth, create challenge auth, verify challenge response of lambda trigger.
please let me know if you request more information to solve this problem. thankyou.
